# How to scroll parent page with iFrame reload

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll

I have a page with a long iframe on it, which loads a schedule display with pages of various lengths. When a new page is displayed in the iframe though, the main page is often still showing the bottom of the page (lots of whitespace). How can I have the main page scroll to the top anytime a new page is loaded in the iframe?

[This is the page](http://kzsc.org/schedule/)

I've tried this is jQuery (on the parent page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#body iframe').load(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` for the `.ready()` call, and you shouldn't have a `#` before `body`.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('body iframe').load(function(){
         $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

With those corrections, the window jumps back to the top when the new content loads.