# JQuery $('iframe').ready why doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a very long iframe inside my parent page. When you reload or click on a link inside i frame's page it is loaded inside it but the purent window must be scroll up.

I have tried variuos code example:[jquery which event is better thatn this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892848/jquery-which-event-is-better-than-this/7893922#7893922) and 
[How to scroll parent page with iFrame reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120813/how-to-scroll-parent-page-with-iframe-reload)
Parent page body code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').load(function(){
         $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });
});</script>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="1000" id="iframe" src="http://mysite.com" width="800"></iframe>
```

And now this is my final code in parent page: (that doesn't work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('iframe').ready(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="1000" id="iframe" align="top" src="http://foicam.altervista.org/listadinamica.php" width="800" ></iframe>
```

but the problem is that each code scroll up the parent page AFTER the frame is compleately loaded (images include). Whant i want is that the **parent page scrolls up BEFORE iframe has finished to load**.

if you click on last image or scroll down the page and then reload only iframe you'll see what i mean!

Thanx a lot, and sorry but I discovered the existence of this language iesterday afternoon!!!

Comment: You have not explained why you dumped the first code block for a code block which does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="1000" id="iframe" align="top" src="http://foicam.altervista.org/listadinamica.php" width="800" ></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('iframe').ready(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
```

Your script is being called before your iframe is part of your DOM. If you put your script after your iframe is part of your DOM, it will recognize it and `$('iframe')` will actually find the object.

Comment: It doesn't wark at all... :-(

Answer (score 3):

The script appears before the iframe in the source, and doesn't have anything to delay its execution (such as being called in `onready`).

Consequently, when it executes, the iframe has not been added to the DOM, and the selector doesn't find the frame. The event handler will only be bound to any iframes that appear *earlier* in the source.

Comment: So...the solution what can be?

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand. I don't want to delay the execution of the script!!! Is the opposite! The script now run AFTER the frame is loaded. I want run it each time the frame change src...please help!

Comment: @Quentin I know I'm coming in a little late to this, but "The first paragraph of my answer says that the problem is caused by X and Y. Change either X or Y so it is no longer true." is just a crude response. If you don't know how to do it, how can you expect the person asking to know? It was such a poor response that it caused someone else to come along and comment on it long after it was made.