# Why I can't select an iframe via $('#iframeid') via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page with a iframe:

`<iframe id="a"></iframe>`

I have jQuery on it and when I use:

`$('#a')` or `$('iframe#a')`, I can't get the element. What I get is a `[]` exactly like I am querying a non-exist HTML node.

Update: I want to select the `<iframe>` tag and do something to it, for example, remove it or change its height. I am NOT going to control the HTML inside that iframe.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: Is the document in the iFrame coming from the same server? If not, the answer is: you can't as it's not a part of your document.

Comment: I want to select the iframe and do something to it, for example, remove it or change its height. I am not going to control the HTML inside that iframe.

Comment: ah, gotcha. Hmm...can you post any more of your HTML?

Comment: It seems to work in this jsfiddle (at least in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/cWf3B/ there must be something else going on with your markup.

Comment: probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899737/jquery-iframe-ready-why-doesnt-work?rq=1 , you have to put the scripts at the end to be executed after the render of the DOM (and the iframe)

Comment: `$('iframe').ready` triggers when the HTML inside the iframe is totally loaded?

Comment: @DA - that demo doesn't prove that the iframe is found, but this slightly updated version does: http://jsfiddle.net/cWf3B/1/ To the OP: you shouldn't need to wait for the content in the iframe to load before manipulating the iframe element itself from the parent. But within the parent you can't manipulate the iframe from JS unless your script element appears after the iframe and/or you use a document ready or onload handler _on the parent_.

Comment: @nnnnnn The `iframe` is dynamically created by jQuery like this: `$('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>`);` And I am quite sure the script is after that.

Comment: The iframe you are appending doesn't appear to have an ID

Comment: @DA it's weird I can't edit that comment. Actually it does. Sorry I forgot to add it! And I remembered that I was trying it in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/t925e/ I used a `Math.random()` to create the iframe

Answer (score 1):

This question is a good example of why it's *so useful* to show us all the relevant code in a fiddle. :)

Your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t925e

As you note in the comments, you are using math.random() to append to the ID name. This is your issue.

Let's take a sample of what math.random() will return:

```
0.8400670071132481
```

So using that and appending it to your ID, you end up with this:

```
iframeid0.8400670071132481
```

Which is not a valid ID value (you can't have a period in your ID)

The other issue is that your jQuery selector is now looking for for something with an ID of "iframeid0" and a class of "8400670071132481"--which doesn't exist on your page.

I'm not sure why you need a random ID, but if you do, the solution is to get rid of the decimal in it. One easy way to accomplish this is to use math.floor() and a multiplier.

For example

```
var ss = Math.floor(1000*Math.random());
```

That will give you a random whole number between 0 and 999. Increase your multiplier if you need a larger range than that.